# Using "or" command in if function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.8 version

I want to shorten my code but i could not find a way to short '#Player 1 and player 2 function'. My knowledge of python is limited with only this functions (if, elif, else, while and for). Please post any solution to my question. It would be better to me learning new tricks and functions.

I have tried this but it didn't work. I can't understand why this code didn't work.

```
if a1g == a2 or b2 or c2:
    Cows1.add("a")
```

Here is my code for Basic bulls and cows game

```
from time import sleep
from random import shuffle

print("        ----------------------------------")
print("        -         BULLS AND COWS         -")
print("        ----------------------------------\n\n")
#sets
Cows1 = set()
Cows2 = set()
Bulls1 = set()
Bulls2 = set()

#creating numbers without dublicates
number1 = list(range(1,10))
number2 = list(range(1,10))
shuffle(number1)
shuffle(number2)
#player 1
a1 = number1[0]
b1 = number1[1]
c1 = number1[2]
d1 = number1[3]
number_player1 = [a1,b1,c1,d1]
#player 2
a2 = number2[0]
b2 = number2[1]
c2 = number2[2]
d2 = number2[3]
number_player2 = [a2,b2,c2,d2]
sleep(1)
ask_user = input("Do you want to see created numbers  ? (yes/no): ")
if ask_user == 'yes':
    sleep(1)
    print("Player 1's numbers:")
    print(number_player1)
    print("Players 2's numbers:")
    print(number_player2)
if ask_user == 'Yes':
    sleep(1)
    print("Player 1's numbers:")
    print(number_player1)
    print("Players 2's numbers:")
    print(number_player2)

#main loop
while True:
#player 1 guesses
    sleep(1)
    print("\nPlayer 1 guess:\n")
    sleep(1)
    a1g = int(input("Number 1: "))
    b1g = int(input("Number 2: "))
    c1g = int(input("Number 3: "))
    d1g = int(input("Number 4: "))
#player 1 function
    if a1g == a2:
        Bulls1.add("a")
    elif a1g is b2 :
        Cows1.add("a")
    elif a1g is c2:
        Cows1.add("a")
    elif a1g is d2:
        Cows1.add("a")

    if b1g == b2:
        Bulls1.add("b")
    elif b1g is a2:
        Cows1.add("b")
    elif b1g is c2:
        Cows1.add("b")
    elif b1g is d2:
        Cows1.add("b")

    if c1g == c2:
        Bulls1.add("c")
    elif c1g is b2:
        Cows1.add("c")
    elif c1g is a2:
        Cows1.add("c")
    elif c1g is d2:
        Cows1.add("c")

    if d1g == d2:
        Bulls1.add("d")
    elif d1g is b2:
        Cows1.add("d")
    elif d1g is c2:
        Cows1.add("d")
    elif d1g is a2:
        Cows1.add("d")
    if len(Bulls1) == 4:
        print("\nPLAYER 1 WON")
        sleep(1)
        print("Player 1 numbers:\n")
        print(number_player1)
        sleep(1)
        print("Player 2 numbers:\n")
        print(number_player2)
        sleep(1)
        exit(input("Press enter to exit"))

#player 1 bull and cow
    print(f"{len(Bulls1)} Bull")
    print(f"{len(Cows1)} Cow")

#player 2 guesses
    print("\nPlayer 2 guess:\n")
    sleep(1)
    a2g = int(input("Number 1: "))
    b2g = int(input("Number 2: "))
    c2g = int(input("Number 3: "))
    d2g = int(input("Number 4: "))
#player 2 function
    if a2g == a1:
        Bulls2.add("a")
    elif a2g == b1 :
        Cows2.add("a")
    elif a2g == c1:
        Cows2.add("a")
    elif a2g == a1:
        Cows2.add("a")

    if b2g == b1:
        Bulls2.add("b")
    elif b2g == a1:
        Cows2.add("b")
    elif b2g == c1:
        Cows2.add("b")
    elif b2g == d1:
        Cows2.add("b")

    if c2g == c1:
        Bulls2.add("c")
    elif c2g == b1:
        Cows2.add("c")
    elif c2g == a1:
        Cows2.add("c")
    elif c2g == d1:
        Cows2.add("c")

    if d2g == d1:
        Bulls2.add("d")
    elif d2g == b1:
        Cows2.add("d")
    elif d2g == c1:
        Cows2.add("d")
    elif d2g == a1:
        Cows2.add("d")
    if len(Bulls2) == 4:
        print("\nPLAYER 2 WON")
        sleep(1)
        print("Player 1 numbers:\n")
        print(number_player1)
        sleep(1)
        print("Player 2 numbers:\n")
        print(number_player2)
        sleep(1)
        exit(input("Press enter to exit"))
#player 1 bull and cow
    print(f"{len(Bulls2)} Bull")
    print(f"{len(Cows2)} Cow")
    Cows1.clear()
    Cows2.clear()
    Bulls1.clear()
    Bulls2.clear()
```

Comment: You need to write the full condition after 'or' like this : `if a1g == a2 or a1g == b2 or a1g == c2:`

Comment: It's not a "command".

Answer (score 0):

`or` is meant to be used with full expressions on both sides, not to give a list of possible matches.  There are two ways to fix your statement:

```
if a1g == a2 or a1g == b2 or a1g == c2:
```

Or take a different approach altogether:

```
if a1g in (a2, b2, c2):
```

Comment: thank you very much, but what is happening with my first code I don't understand. Could you explain ? ```

if a1g == a2 or b2 or c2:
    Cows1.add("a")

```